# Having trouble copying data from one sheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

Developing a large macro and now it seems the second simplest part is giving me trouble.

I am able to copy the selection in one workbook, but it does not allow me to paste over to the other workbook.  I am getting:

> "Object doesn't support this property or method" error.

This is looping through large sets of data so it will need to be able to rinse and repeat, which shouldn't be a problem because I can just clear the clipboard as a rinse method.

Any ideas?

Code below. There is code above it, but I don't think you should need any of it to get an idea of what's going on.  Error comes in on the ** line.

```
Do
DoEvents
    'Tests condition for counter party
    If InStr(1, Range(buyerCol & row_counter), clientName) > 0 Or InStr(1, Range(sellerCol & row_counter), clientName) > 0 Then
        EEB.Sheets("Trades Master List").Rows(row_counter).Copy

        'Activates newly created excel sheet
        Workbooks(newWorkbookName).Activate

        'Tests newly created sheet for already existing entries and increments newSheetRow by 1 until it finds the next empty space
        Do While IsEmpty(Range("A" & newSheetRow)) = False
            newSheetRow = newSheetRow + 1
        Loop

        **ActiveWorkbook.Range(newSheetRow & newSheetRow).PasteSpecial
        EEB.masterList.Activate
        row_counter = row_counter + 1
    Else
        row_counter = row_counter + 1
    End If

Loop Until Range("A" & row_counter).Value > endDateFromSheet Or IsEmpty(Range("A" & row_counter)) = True
```

Comment: You need to specify the sheet ie `ActiveWorkbook.Sheet(1).Range...`

Comment: Hi Scott   still receiving the same error with that change

Comment: Is it possible to refactor your code to use the destination argument in the `.Copy` function?

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Sheet(1).Range("A" & newSheetRow).PasteSpecial` the way you had it you were saying `Range(1 & 1)` which become `Range(11)`, which does not work

Comment: @ScottCraner is correct. In the editor type out `activeworkbook.` After the period Intellisense will list all the available methods and properties of that object. Range is not a property or method of `activeworkbook`. That is why you are getting errors. Also, look into using properties like `.sheet1.usedrange.rows.count` to find your empty cells. And if you are only checking the value of one cell, use something like `.cells(row_counter, buyerCol)` instead of ranges.

Comment: Hi gents, much appreciated for all the help.  Unfortunately I am still receving an error when using scotts code above.  Any idea why that might be?  I apologize i'm new to VBA so the syntax is still new. I am copying a row and pasting it over into another row

Comment: When it stops what is the value of `newSheetRow`? you can hover over the variable in the code and it will tell you.  My guess is it is 0, because the first row is empty and it never assigns a value to it.  Instead of your loop to find the next empty row put this `newSheetRow = ActiveWorkbook.Sheet(1).Range("A60000").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: I had initialized it to one earlier in the code.  I added your method instead of the loop and that works properly and now the line will execute, but it does something really strange in that after it executes it jumps to another Public function in the excel book Which is very odd.  Any idea why that could happen? lol Thank you so much for all your help I really appreciate it.

Comment: Changed it to a Private Sub and it resolved the issue.  Thank you for all your help